# media query for mobile showing different alignment in different mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile, alignment, media-queries

i have a website done in html and css, I have used media query coz in mobile view one row in my website was showing wrong alignment, so id did the following code for mobile devices:

```html
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {

#zayan {margin-left: -20%;}
#amir {margin-top: -20%; width: 100px;}
#amir h5 {font-size: 12px; margin-left: -40%;}


}
```

now I checked this in my redmi note 8 mobile and it was showing perfect, but when i checked it in my redmi 7 and another device its coming wrong,

can anyone please tell me what could be wrong here. thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried it on my devices and I hope this works for you

```
@media all and (max-width: 600px) {

    #zayan {margin: auto; }
    #amir h5 { font-size: 12px; }
    #amir { margin-top: -20%; }

    .card-body{ padding: 0px !important; }

}
```

Comment: what was the issue bro?

Comment: Can you upload a screenshot of the correct and problematic view